# javaEE8 app REST stopped working after adding keycloak-admin-client artifact

Tags: rest, keycloak, java-ee-8

a javaEE8, wildfly-20.0.1 app REST service stopped working after adding keycloak-admin-client 18.0.2 artifact.

Thanks in advance for your help

```
 <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>javax</groupId>
         <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
         <version>8.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
         <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
         <version>18.0.2</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="       http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee       http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
   <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

```
@Path("javaee8")
public class JavaEE8Resource {
    
    @GET
    public Response ping(){
        return Response
                .ok("ping")
                .build();
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

removing reasteasy conflict solved the problem:

```
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
         <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
         <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
         <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```